# How output structure in C++

Tags: c++, wnet

In my program I want to get  user's local groups. My code is:

```
LPLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 pBuf = NULL; //STRUCTURE
DWORD dwLevel = 0;
DWORD dwFlags = LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT ; 
DWORD dwPrefMaxLen = MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH; 
DWORD dwEntriesRead = 0;
DWORD dwTotalEntries = 0; 
NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
nStatus = NetUserGetLocalGroups(NULL,
                               L"Nastya",
                               dwLevel,
                               dwFlags,
                               (LPBYTE *) &pBuf,
                               dwPrefMaxLen,
                               &dwEntriesRead,
                               &dwTotalEntries);
DWORD i;
```

I want to output pBuf:

```
if (nStatus == NERR_Success) 
{
   wprintf(L"\t-- %s\n", pBuf->lgrui0_name);
}
```

But I get only first element "HomeUsers". 
How can I get all elements of this structure?

```
typedef struct _LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0 {
  LPWSTR lgrui0_name;
} LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0, *PLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0, *LPLOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
```

Comment: Why don't you read the example code given on the documentation page for `NetUserGetLocalGroups`?

Comment: I read it but I didn't  understand some things and want to write myself. But I cant ouput pBuf

Comment: How can I solve it? Please, help me.

Comment: C++ structures represent the layout of bits in memory with only minimal language machinery on top. Unlike javascript objects, there is no simple way to enumerate the fields, and you must simply print out each field explicitly.